# How does the Apple iTunes web site launch the iTunes application on my computer when I click the blue "Launch iTunes" button?

Tags: itunes

This is new to me as a desktop developer.

If I could figure out how this is accomplished, it may be relevant to some research I'm doing, specifically how to migrate thick desktop apps to a web implementation.

The more forms-oriented and lightweight graphics I can figure out, but heavyweight 3D graphics still requires some form of non-browser application.

As nearly as I can determine, iTunes installs some form of new protocol handler on my machine, corresponding to "itms", in place of "http".

This is cool and mysterious to me, almost magical. Any help or suggestions for additional reading materials and/or resources would be very welcome.

Comment: Windows for the present, but I have ideas...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can register "protocol handlers" with some browsers. I think there's a place in the operating system where you can regsiter your own.

See

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588696(office.11).aspx
- http://blog.ryaneby.com/archives/firefox-protocol-handlers/

Creating new ones in firefox: http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-custom-protocol-handlers-with-html-5-and-firefox

In safari: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1280989

Special "mobile protocol handlers" are used extensively in the iPhone/iPod to launch the phone dialler, email sending, google maps and so on... http://www.iphonedevfaq.com/index.php?title=Protocols

Here's an **example of how to reconfigure the `mailto:` protocol handler** to trigger gmail rather than an external mail client: http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links

Comment: If you want to add your own protocol handler you have to configure your web browser - and possibly your operating system/UI shell (I'm guessing that's how it would be done with IE & Safari.) For security reasons it would be dangerous to allow any old javascript downloaded off the web to reconfigure your browser to trigger apps on your desktop.

Comment: in chrome: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler

Answer (score 7):

Simple.

```
<a href="itunes:///">Open iTunes</a>
```

Most apps now-a-days have "Custom URL Schemes"
For Example - Coda (http://panic.com/coda) you can add snippets of code via:

```
<a href="codaclips:///<<**Title:NAME**>>blabla">Add Clip</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I have to delve into protocol handlers and how to create them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. As I said, much of the functionality can be accomodated directly in the browser via HTML/AJAX or Flex or Silverlight. Its the heavy duty graphics that probably cannot be. In this case, I want to launch a separate, pre-installed application which specifically handles the 3D stuff. By heavy-duty I mean tens of millions of vertices, and millions of quads/triangles.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows this is called a Pluggable Protocol Handler.  [This article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DataProtocol.aspx) shows how to implement a pluggable protocol handler on Windows.

Note, this is more involved then just registering a new protocol in the registry, such as myprotocol:// and having it start a specific exe whenever a myprotocol:// anchor is clicked.

It actually allows your application to receive and process the request and to create response data dynamically.  If your protocol will also be called programmatically this is usually important.

This may be overkill for your situation however it is handy to know about.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to register a filetype to your application (also called File Association), for example ".myp" and when the user press "start myapp" on the site it downloads a file "startapp.myp".

Windows will then look at the extention of the file and find that it is registered to your app and start your application with the file as a command-parameter. Your app can then read the file and do stuff depending of it contents.

Here are code to register a filetype to your application done in VB.Net:
(Example is taken from http://www.developerfusion.com/article/36/file-assocation/2/ but copied here for persistent reason, check original site for comments)

```
'// Registry windows api calls
Private Declare Function RegCreateKey& Lib "advapi32.DLL" Alias "RegCreateKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpszSubKey As String, ByVal lphKey As Long)
Private Declare Function RegSetValue& Lib "advapi32.DLL" Alias "RegSetValueA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpszSubKey As String, ByVal fdwType As Long, ByVal lpszValue As String, ByVal dwLength As Long)
'// Required constants
Private Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
Private Const MAX_PATH = 256&
Private Const REG_SZ = 1

'// procedure you call to associate the tmg extension with your program.
Private Sub MakeDefault()
    Dim sKeyName As String  '// Holds Key Name in registry.
    Dim sKeyValue As String  '// Holds Key Value in registry.
    Dim ret As Long    '// Holds error status if any from API calls.
    Dim lphKey As Long    '// Holds created key handle from RegCreateKey.

    '// This creates a Root entry called "TextMagic"
    sKeyName = "TextMagic" '// Application Name
    sKeyValue = "TextMagic Document" '// File Description
    ret = RegCreateKey&(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, sKeyName, lphKey)
    ret = RegSetValue&(lphKey&, Empty, REG_SZ, sKeyValue, 0&)

    '// This creates a Root entry called .tmg associated with "TextMagic".
    sKeyName = ".tmg" '// File Extension
    sKeyValue = "TextMagic" '// Application Name
    ret = RegCreateKey&(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, sKeyName, lphKey)

    ret = RegSetValue&(lphKey, Empty, REG_SZ, sKeyValue, 0&)

    '//This sets the command line for "TextMagic".
    sKeyName = "TextMagic" '// Application Name
    If Right$(App.Path, 1) = "\" Then
        sKeyValue = App.Path & App.EXEName & ".exe %1" '// Application Path
    Else
        sKeyValue = App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe %1" '// Application Path
    End If
    ret = RegCreateKey&(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, sKeyName, lphKey)
    ret = RegSetValue&(lphKey, "shell\open\command", REG_SZ, sKeyValue, MAX_PATH)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    '// ensure we only register once. When debugging etc, remove the SaveSetting line, so your program will
    '// always attempt to register the file extension
    If GetSetting(App.Title, "Settings", "RegisteredFile", 0) = 0 Then
        '// associate tmg extension with this app
        MakeDefault()
        SaveSetting(App.Title, "Settings", "RegisteredFile", 1)
    End If
   '// check command line argument:
    If Command$ <> Empty Then
        '// we have a file to open
        '// Fetch the file name from Command$ and then read the file if needed.
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up for those who answered.

Turns out that the situation is somewhat complicated. Although about:config is available for FireFox, making the appropriate entries just doesn't work.

This link: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=fr&forumId=1&comments_parentId=74068 describes problems for Linux, but I can verify that the same problems also occur under Windows.

To make this work under Windows, I had to create a .REG file which contains the appropriate information, according to this link: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#Windows

Now it works!

Thanks for all the responses.