# Start exe application from website

Tags: asp.net, exe

I have a `webpage` in `ASP.NET`.
And I have an `.exe` application which created using `C#`.
First, the user have to download the `.exe` application and should copy it to the `C:\`.
That I can give the instruction in the webpage.
Using a `link` in the webpage, I need to open that particular `.exe` application.
I tried the following **Code:**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
......
......
......
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\app.exe");
Process.Start(info);
```

This working fine locally, but when I uploaded it in the `webserver`, I got the following `Exception`.

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Then I searched in `Google` and found how the `iTunes` launches from the website.
Like from the following link.
[Launches iTunes.exe from here](https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/pardes-from-jerusalem/id80028216?mt=2)

Then I tried to open the iTunes using the following `link`.

```
<a href="itunes:///">Open iTunes</a>
```

It worked perfectly, but I tried the same with my `.exe` application, it didn't open and at the same time it showed the following **error**.

```
HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.
```

So can anyone guide me to open my `.exe` application from my `webpage`.
And if the `.exe` is there in `Bin` folder on `server`, then how can I go about it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)

Comment: Check the path to exe file on server.

Comment: @L-Three: I read this. I tried also. From this link only I got the idea of iTunes.

Comment: @PeterJ app.exe is there in the local system.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\app.exe");
Process.Start(info);
```

starts a new service on the server not on the client computer. You get an error message because there is no "C:\app.exe" on your server.

You cannot launch an application on local computer from asp.net server application.

Itunes is using a "protocol handler", read [How does the Apple iTunes web site launch the iTunes application on my computer when I click the blue "Launch iTunes" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780211/how-does-the-apple-itunes-web-site-launch-the-itunes-application-on-my-computer)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @smirnov: How can I achieve that?

Comment: You cannot launch an application on local computer from asp.net server application.